# Check the value of a variable at compile time / templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

So, we have this:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
void fun(const T& val)
{
    std::cout << "val >= 0";
}

int main()
{
    fun(34);
}
```

Imagine we have other overloads of the function. How would I get the above function overload to only compile when the value of `val` is larger than `0`?

On http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral I see that `operator()` is overloaded for `std::is_integral` and it returns the `value` so I tried this:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value() > 0>>
```

Of course, it looks wrong, and it is wrong as the compiler graciously lets me know.

How do I check the value of the variable at compile time?

Comment: The variable doesn't have a value at compile time, only at run time.

Comment: @AlanStokes Only option is to have the value as a template parameter itself? template<std::size_t value>

Comment: Or you could perhaps look at a `constexpr` function.

Comment: You've misread the documentation – If you have an object `t` of type `is_integral<T>`, then `t()` is equivalent to `is_integral<T>::value`. The member `value` itself is a `bool`. (And `is_integral` is a predicate on *types*, not values.)

Comment: @AlanStokes how is a `constexpr` function supposed to help in verifying an argument's value at compile-time?

Comment: @Piotr It depends whether the values at the call sites are constants (which they would have to be to be used as template parameters). It seemed like it might be relevant, although given the absence of any description of the actual problem to be solved it's hard to tell.

Comment: @AlanStokes a `constexpr` function can be evaluated at compile time if its arguments are constant expressions at a call site, but the arguments are not usable in constant expressions themselves

Comment: @AlanStokes and one doesn't have to be marked constexpr to put a static assert in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Functions input parameters value is determined at run-time. Thus, SFINAE won't help at this neither will any else compile time trickery.

What you can do is attack the problem at runtime and define two independent functions that are going to be evoked accordingly:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
void fun(const T& val)
{
    (val < 0)? lower_than_zero(val) : greater_equal_than_zero(val);
}
```

But probably you knew that already. If you're still in for compile time evaluation and you're sure that your variable is a compile time beast. Then you could pass it as a template non-type argument:

```
template<int N>
std::enable_if_t<N >= 0> fun() {
  std::cout << "N >= 0" << std::endl;
}

template<int N>
std::enable_if_t<N < 0> fun() {
  std::cout << "N < 0" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  fun<42>();
  fun<-42>();
}
```

Comment: but suppose that `val`'s value is available at compile time, for example using not type template parameter (make any necessary assumption please), then it could have done using `if` statement? Thanks

Comment: @AngelusMortis what you're describing is a static if. Unfortunately, C++ doesn't have a static if. At least not yet.

Comment: So it means `if` always evaluates it's expression at run time and branches accordingly? Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

As @101010 answered there is no way to do this in general way.
But if you need to check only one condition `>= 0`, then you can do this:

```
void ff(unsigned int val) {
    val = 42;
}

int main()
{
    ff(34);
    ff(-34);
}
```

and compile like this:

```
g++ 1.cpp -Werror -Wsign-conversion
```

But it's just a hack for one special case.